# Tag merge requests

Tags: support, stack-overflow, retag-request, synonym-request

I came across a few tags that need merging (and have too many questions to retag manually):

- [bot](/questions/tagged/bot) and [bots](/questions/tagged/bots)
- [submit](/questions/tagged/submit), [form-submit](/questions/tagged/form-submit) and [form-submission](/questions/tagged/form-submission) (form-submit might be the least ambiguous), also [submission](/questions/tagged/submission) needs sorting out, the questions are mostly about submitting apps but there are some HTML form questions there as well
- [rotate](/questions/tagged/rotate), [rotation](/questions/tagged/rotation) and [rotating](/questions/tagged/rotating) (it'd be nice if people used more specific tags like [screen-rotation](/questions/tagged/screen-rotation) or [image-rotation](/questions/tagged/image-rotation), but it'd be a huge undertaking to retag all ~2500 questions)
- [ads](/questions/tagged/ads), [advertising](/questions/tagged/advertising) and [advertisement](/questions/tagged/advertisement), maybe also [marketing](/questions/tagged/marketing)
- [prevent](/questions/tagged/prevent) and [prevention](/questions/tagged/prevention) (would be better if deleted, only ~170 questions so could be done manually)

Answer (score 2):

I'm proceeding judiciously here.  That said.

- I've merged [bot](/questions/tagged/bot) into [bots](/questions/tagged/bots)
- I've merge [rotate](/questions/tagged/rotate) and [rotating](/questions/tagged/rotating) into [rotate](/questions/tagged/rotate)
- <del>I'm manually removing</del> I've removed [prevent](/questions/tagged/prevent) and [prevention](/questions/tagged/prevention) from the questions they're on.  It's a meta tag, and we aren't too keen on those.

Here are my thoughts on the others:

- [form-submit](/questions/tagged/form-submit) and [form-submission](/questions/tagged/form-submission) could probably be merged, but I'm not sure if [submit](/questions/tagged/submit) should be in there, as it's it could be the `input` type on an HTML form (which I know, plays a part in form submission as well)
- [submission](/questions/tagged/submission) does need sorting out.  Generally, I think removing this and replacing it (if possible) on questions which have better tags should be performed
- I don't have a *major* problem with replacing [rotation](/questions/tagged/rotation) with [screen-rotation](/questions/tagged/screen-rotation), [image-rotation](/questions/tagged/image-rotation) (or something else better-suited), but [rotation](/questions/tagged/rotation) isn't a *horrible* offender, right now.
- [ads](/questions/tagged/ads), [advertising](/questions/tagged/advertising) and [advertisement](/questions/tagged/advertisement) need to be looked at more to see what they're really trying to get at.  If the question is about advertising in general, then I propose removing the tag, voting to close (if you have the ability to) and flagging for moderator attention to be closed as Off Topic.  I'd like to see more specific tagging around all three of these (or whatever they are decided to be merged into)